# Join folders in windows server 2k12r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows Server 2012r2.  And due to poor planning on my side, i did not allocate enough space for the my documents folder.

I have added a new hard drive in the system, now I would like to have all of my documents folder be saved or joined on the new E drive.

I thought there was a 'join directory' command, but i cannot remember the actual name.

thank you
tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a couple of things.

1. Mount the new drive inside of your users folder. You do this through disk management (diskmgmt.msc). If you do this, it won't have a drive letter.
2. Configure your server to store profiles on the E:\ drive, and copy all of the profiles that are currently on C:\ to E:\

Comment: I love the idea of storing profiles on alternate locations...   would you suggest a good link so i learn more about the correct way to implement this?  thank you

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/redefine-userprofile/e011afa5-e104-4a73-a1c6-54d22f8c02d3

Comment: this solution has provided me with the SAME results as the user that finished up with this comment...    Edit:

So Mo--- Fu--ing awesome: I am not allowed to access Explorer.exe any more.  I can't open My Computer or the Control Pannel.  AWESOME.